# Invalid US-ASCII character "\xC2" in rails 3.1 production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Every time i start my server in production mode i get this error mesage

```
Invalid US-ASCII character "\xC2"
  (in /home/rzaartz/rails/school/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
```

Pls any help about this kind  of error

Comment: it works without errors in development environment

Comment: what are the ruby versions in your dev environment and your production environment?

Comment: Are you by any chance including this file? http://github.com/necolas/normalize.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem when running `rake assets:precompile` . For me the problem was in `normalize.css`---a character in the first line comment wasn't being understood by the asset compiler.

If you are including this file, replace the 'center-dot' with a dash. (Note that this change has been committed already by [polarblau](https://github.com/polarblau/normalize.css/commit/e2b5b0ef3fc8b482b1f822a7b5c77db90e873a8a)). If you're not using normalize look somewhere in your sass includes for the center-dot and remove it.

Comment: This isn't actually a solution to the problem. It's just a work-around. The problem is that your system is using US-ASCII charset when it should be using UTF-8. I've run into this same issue and I'm trying to figure out how to actually fix it.

Answer (score 0):

(for fellow googlers)

As stated [here](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails/issues/66#issuecomment-23355629), a simple solution is to explicitely declare you scss encoding in the main(s) scss :

`@charset "UTF-8";`

Comment: Sadly, it seems like I have to add this to every scss-file, which is not an option. Is there another workaround?